# Has anybody use javafx on CDC J9?

Tags: java, javafx, cdc

Is that possible?? 
I mean, I have an already working project that runs in windows mobile using the J9 virtual machine for CDC. My user interface there is using AWT and it works fine and it looks OK, but been honest it doesn't take real advantage of the devices were is running...
So I start reading about JavaFX and that looks really cool, but all that I see about mobiles there is applied to CLDC, MIDP, etc. but my application is already running on CDC J9 and I can't change this cause I'm using a Derby database on it.

So, my plan is to code the GUI again, but keeping the logic of the application. So do you guys think javafx is the way to go? or, am I wasting my time learning javafx for this project.

Thanks in advance,

Gustavo.

Answer (score 0):

If the UI is looking ok then I wouldn't do it again in JavaFX. The biggest plus you gain with JavaFX is a very nice UI which can be developed relative fast.

See here for [windows mobile support](http://javafx.com/downloads/all.jsp), but for the user JavaFX must be preinstalled in the OS and to be honest: I don't know if this is the case for **any** current mobile OS.

See [this FAQ](http://www.javafx.com/faq/#2.4) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX works with CLDC for Mobile platforms and CDC on TV Platforms, and only with Oracle JVMs.